# Pivot Table with Multiple Columns having the same Categorical Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm hoping to build a pivot table that has multiple columns all using the same type of categories. However, I don't want them to create a hierarchy since I just want a summary for each column.

Here's the situation: We have teachers submit data through shared Excel documents as they complete assessments. I've created a Query that pulls all the data together into a new workbook where I can see all of the data. We have some Math assessments that are given categorical grades (in this case NY, B, and M). But, there are multiple assessments like this.

What I'm hoping to do is create a Pivot table that would end up looking something like this:

```
              Assessment1 || Assessment2  || Assessment3 || ...
              NY | B | M  ||  NY | B | M  ||  NY | B | M   
SchoolA     
  TeacherA     1   2   3      4   5   6        7  8  9
  TeacherB     1   2   3      4   5   6        7  8  9 
SchoolB
  TeacherC     1   2   3      4   5   6        7  8  9  
  TeacherD     1   2   3      4   5   6        7  8  9  
...
```

I have been able to make this manually using a table, but I'm hoping to use a Pivot Table so I can utilize some of the filters we'd like to look at (things like different demographics) without making a separate table for each possibility. Is this even possible through Pivot Tables?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are looking for, but having data in the proper format will enable to create a pivot table like this.

This looks like what you are looking for, right? You can add slicers for your demographics, such as zip code.

[image]